# How to add layouts to ViewFlipper and change views' values

Tags: android, viewflipper

I want to fill a ViewFlipper with layouts like this, programmatically:

flippercontainer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/breakfast" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Name of product"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="40dp"
                android:text="Cafeteria" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Delivery" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtCaf"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="40dp"
                android:text="$" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="$" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But, I want to change the ImageView's background, and the text of the TextViews that have an id.
I get NullPointerException if I try that like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.flippercontainer, null );
name=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
name.setText("View number "+ i);
```

In the last line.
How can I populate a ViewFlipper programmatically, and change the values I want to? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each layout of the flipperview will be the same as this-
flippercontainter.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:padding="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Name of product"
    android:textColor="#31B6E7"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCaf"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:text="$" />

</LinearLayout>
```

On the activity with the viewflipper:

```
private void setFlipperContent() {
    List<Stuff> aux=getStuffList();
    end = aux.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.flippercontainer, null);

        flipper.addView(view);

        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        image.setBackgroundResource(aux.get(i).getImg());
        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        name.setText(aux.get(i).getName());
        cafPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCaf);
        cafPrice.setText("$" + aux.get(i).getCafPrice());
    }
    setFlipperAnimation();
}
```